Difficulty in understanding the proof of Poincaré's theorem for cosets.
Let $H, K<G$ have finite index. Then $[G:H\cap K]\le[G:H][G:K]$.
Proof. Let $[G:H]=m$, $[G:K]=n$, and denote the (distinct) left cosets of $H$ and $K$ by $a_1H,\ ...,\ a_mH$ and $b_1K,\ ...,\ b_nK$ respectively. Then $a_iH\cap b_jK=e_{ij}(H\cap K)$ for some $e_{ij}\in a_iH\cap b_j K$ given any $i,j$. But $x(H\cap K)=xH\cap xK$ whenever $x\in G$? With this contradiction, we arrive at the theorem.
Question. I do not understand why it is needed to show that $a_iH\cap b_jK=e_{ij}(H\cap K)$ for some $e_{ij}\in a_iH\cap b_j K$? We can directly see that $x(H\cap K)=xH\cap xK$ $\forall x\in G$, and there are exactly $mn$ intersections of left cosets of $H$ with left cosets of $K$.
Please someone clarify this doubt. Thank you.

The idea of the proof is to show that $[G:H \cap K] \leqslant [G:H][G:K]$ by establishing a surjection of the form $G/H \times G/K \to G/(H \cap K)$. The proposed map is $(a_iH, b_jK) \mapsto a_iH \cap b_jK$. Of course, this may not be well-defined since the intersection may be empty, so what we should really do is make the domain $S \subseteq G/H \times G/K$ where $a_iH \cap b_jK$ is non-empty.
Anyways, you need to show that $a_iH \cap b_jK$ is indeed a coset of $H \cap K$, which is why you want to prove that $a_iH \cap b_jK = e_{ij}(H \cap K)$ for some $e_{ij} \in G$. Now that you have a well-defined map, you can then check surjectivity. Indeed, the fact $x(H \cap K) = xH \cap xK$ achieves precisely this.

I think the codomain you wanted to write is $G/H\cap K$.

Yes, thank you!

Thank you too sir
